# Change text in a bootstrap collapse button based on whether the element is collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've had a look at a few threads on here about this but I am having issues ammending the code to fit my design.

I am using Collapse buttons from here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

They work fine but I would like the text and icon to change based on the state of the element.

Minimised: Show More V
Expanded: Show Less ^

I wrote it in 2 scripts because I am quite the gumby with JavaScript:

```
<Script>
$(".collapse").click(function(){
  $(this).hasClass("in")?true : (function(){
      $(this).children("i").removeClass('fa-caret-down');
      $(this).children("i").addClass('fa-caret-up');
  }, function () {
      $(this).children("i").removeClass('fa-caret-up');
      $(this).children("i").addClass('fa-caret-down');
  });
});
</script>

<Script>
$(".collapse").click(function(){
  $(this).hasClass("in")?true : (function(){
      $(this).children("i").removeClass('More');
      $(this).children("i").addClass('Less');
  }, function () {
      $(this).children("i").removeClass('Less');
      $(this).children("i").addClass('More');
  });
});
</script>
```

The names of the elements are all things like collapseBech, collapseTrev etc.

Is this something obvious I am missing?

The HTML

```
<p class="text-justify">The cat sat on the mat</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseBech">
    <p class="text-justify">The cat sat on the mat</p>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseBech" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseBech">
    Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</a>

<p class="text-justify">The cat sat on the mat</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseTrev">
    <p class="text-justify">The cat sat on the mat</p>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTrev" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTrev">
    Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</a>

<p class="text-justify">The cat sat on the mat</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseNat">
    <p class="text-justify">The cat sat on the mat</p>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseNat" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseNat">
    Read More <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/maybolles/tL1ueq7q/

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply but this fiddle doesn't seem to do anything? I could be doing something wrong though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are using the ternary operator is not correct, you are doing:

```
[condition]?true : [code_if_true] , [code_if_false];
```

but the right syntax is:

```
[condition]?  [code_if_true] : [code_if_false];
```

note that you don't use the keyword "true" and the colon (`:`) separates the two code blocks, not a comma as in your code.

However, your code is quite long so the ternary operator is not a good idea, you should use a simple if-else such as:

**EDIT:**

I have changed the code below after seeing your HTML code in your last edit. The problem is that you are triggering the event when someone clicks on the element with class `collapse`, but that's wrong because you click on the button not on the `.collapse` element:

```
$(".collapse").click(function(){}); // This is wrong
```

you need to assign a class, let's call it `clickable-butn`, to each of the buttons, so that later we can apply the `.click()` event to this class:

```
<p class="text-justify">The cat sat on the mat</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseBech">
    <p class="text-justify">The cat sat on the mat</p>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary clickable-butn" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseBech" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseBech">
    <span>Read More </span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</a>

<p class="text-justify">The cat sat on the mat</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseTrev">
    <p class="text-justify">The cat sat on the mat</p>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary clickable-butn" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTrev" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTrev">
    <span>Read More </span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</a>

<p class="text-justify">The cat sat on the mat</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseNat">
    <p class="text-justify">The cat sat on the mat</p>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-primary clickable-butn" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseNat" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseNat">
    <span>Read More </span><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
</a>

<div id="output">
</div>
```

Now let's check how the code would look like:

```
$(".clickable-butn").click(function(){
  // now, $(this) is the button we just clicked...
  // Now let's find the id of the .collapse element that is associated to $(this) button
  var idOfCollapse = $(this).attr("href");
  // now that we know its id, we can check if it is visible
  // note that we are checking if it was visible BEFORE the click...
  if($(idOfCollapse).is(":visible")){ 
      $(this).children("span").text($(this).children("span").text().replace("Less", "More"));
      $(this).children("i").removeClass('fa-caret-down');
      $(this).children("i").addClass('fa-caret-up');
    } else {
      $(this).children("span").text($(this).children("span").text().replace("More", "Less"));
      $(this).children("i").removeClass('fa-caret-up');
      $(this).children("i").addClass('fa-caret-down');
  }
});
```

You will see that when you click the button, the text changes from "Read More" to "Read Less" and vice versa.

Comment: The "this": Is that an element I need to be specifically naming?

Eg: $(#collapsebech)

Comment: No, you should leave it as it is. When you have an event such as `click()`, `$(this)` identifies the element on which the event was applied: in case of a click event, it is the element you clicked on, which in your case is one of the elements with class `.collapse`.

Comment: Perhaps if you add your html to your question I can help you more specifically

Comment: Sorry mate, HTML added.

Comment: Awesome mate, thanks heaps. The only thing is that it seems to just strip the fa-caret-down/fa-caret-up.

I click the button, the text changes but the fa-caret-down icon disappears. Clicking again doesn't make the fa-caret-up appear. I can probably just do away with it if it would be hard to fix.

Comment: Yes you are right, see the updated code, now it works, I have changed both HTML and JS. Reason for the bug: after some testing I realised that's because font-awesome generates characters using css, but that character is then considered text by the browser and it's not handled well when in Jquery we do the `.text().replace()` operation... The solution is to enclose "read more" in a `<span>` and change the javascript that replaces the text so that we replace text only inside that span, e.g. `$(this).children("span").replace(...)`.

Comment: It's interesting. I click the button initially and "More" changes to "Less" but the icon doesn't change. I click it again and "Less" changes to "More" and this time the icon changes. From this point the icon works but is obviously "out of sync".

Comment: Scratch that - I just changed swapped the add/remove in both instances and it is now working flawlessly. Thank you so much mate.

Answer (score 0):

you can use build-in Bootstrap's collapse event

```
$('#collapseBech, #collapseTrev, #collapseNat').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
     // do something…
     $(this).next("a").css({"background": "#ff0000"});
     $(this).next("a").children("i").removeClass('More').addClass('Less').removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
});
$('#collapseBech, #collapseTrev, #collapseNat').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
     // do something…
     $(this).next("a").css({"background": "#00ff00"});
});
```

try this demo

jsfiddle.net/my9z7zhc

Comment: Is this the intended use:

<Script>
$('#collapseBech').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
$(this).children("i").removeClass('Less');
      $(this).children("i").addClass('More');
      $(this).children("i").removeClass('fa-caret-up');
      $(this).children("i").addClass('fa-caret-down');
});
$('#collapseBech').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
      $(this).children("i").removeClass('More');
      $(this).children("i").addClass('Less');
      $(this).children("i").removeClass('fa-caret-down');
      $(this).children("i").addClass('fa-caret-up');
});
</script>